# Google app indexing, how to check if it works on the website

Tags: android, seo, android-app-indexing

I've done a bunch of app-indexing work on our mobile app from tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/) , and it seems to work locally, when I typed something in Google Now launcher box, the historical results show, clicking on it brings to our app. 
However, we track our weburl we submitted when doing app-indexing for the past month, no records of googlebot shown. 
So how do I check whether I did things correctly or the bot really working? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things you can do:

1. Test whether your deep links are correct. You can do that with the Deep Link Testing tool, see [this](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test) doc for information on that.
2. You can measure your deep links performance now, see [here](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/referrer) how to implement this, but basically the referrer information would be passed on in the `Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER` intent for you to extract referrer info.
3. You can use [Search Console](http://google.com/webmasters/tools) both to render your app, and to track its performance. For this you would have to add the app to Search Console (`Add Property`, then add the android app package name: android-app://com.xyz)